# Hybrid tube-solid state amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, vacuum-tube

In a hybrid tube-transistor amplifier (tube front end and solid state follower stage) how is the rail voltage applied? Tubes and transistors have different collector/plate voltages. What is the best way to set these voltages? Do I need to have two different rectifiers?

Comment: The stages are capacitively coupled so that will block any DC offset and only let the audio through. In a few hybrid amps and effects boxes I’ve seen, they run a low plate voltage of around 45V or so on the valve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About 10 years ago I designed and built a 20W (into 8 Ohms) hybrid guitar amp for my personal use, and to get knowledge and experience about valve amplifiers. Memories...

[image]

<sup>KRAMP: **K**ilic **R**ohat **AMP**lification ( please don't laugh :D )</sup>

The preamp section was a 4 stage high gain valve amplifier built with two 12AX7s, and the power amp section was a class-AB push-pull amplifier (completely discrete, no ICs).

The plate voltages for preamp section were 280 ~ 400 VDC (Because of multi-stage RC filtering i.e. highly filtered (and therefore lower) voltage is for the input stage), ±35V for power amp.

For this purpose I ordered a custom transformer: 230V primary, and multiple secondaries: 300V, 25V-0-25V (centre-tapped for PA), 12V (for filaments and low voltage stuff e.g. LEDs, speaker simulated output, relays etc.).

---

If it was today's me I'd go for a multiple output off-line isolated SMPS instead because it'd be lightweight. Also, in a classical iron-core-transformer-based rectification 100 Hz noise (hum) may become more apparent, especially in a high-gain amplifier. In a well-designed SMPS the noise will be in tens of kHz, but layout becomes more important because, as stated in Ed Halfsunk's answer, there's a risk of getting really noisy output.

Today's well-known brands (Fender, Mesa, Orange, etc) still have iron core transformers and rectifiers. Because it's simple.

Comment: Hi, do you share your designs? Do you have a website/ blog? The reason I want to build a hybrid is because of cost, I have built solid state amplifiers before but I haven't tried building valve amps.

Comment: @HarshitBujarBaruah unfortunately there's no webpage, blog or whatever that I shared the design details. I'll have a look at my personal archive to see if there's something useful. You can start from [Valve Wizard](https://www.valvewizard.co.uk) and have a look at the already available commercial schematics such e.g. EVH 5150 III and Soldano SLO-100. They are all over the internet. I also remember a webpage explains the technical details of SLO-100.

Comment: +1 for the kramp, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are going to make one amp, not to start an optimized mass production line. The best depends on what you happen to have. If you happen to have a good low voltage DC supply free to be used for the low voltage stages, use it. Another possibility is to have a DC to DC converter for low voltage or preferably for high voltage, if it's needed only in the preamp.

Warning: Switch mode designs easily generate unwanted noise. One must take this into the account very seriously in the design. Separate high and low voltage power supplies with old-school (transformer-rectifier-filter) design is a safe way. A  common multi-winding transformer is a good idea if such item is available or one can modify an existing one.